# How to check if a string contains an break HTML tag?

Tags: c#, html

I have this expression:

```
if (scheduleString.IndexOf("<br/>") == -1) return scheduleString;
```

I want to check if a string contains `<br/>`.  However, during testing, one of the test strings contained `<br />` (extra space between `br` and `/`).  Is there a way I can handle both cases and any extra spaced cases (ex.  `<br             />`)?

Comment: I would use a regular expression to allow any amount of spaces and still match.

Comment: how performance critical is this?  Do a `string.replace(" ", "")` first to eliminate the spaces would work but won't be that fast for big strings.

It does however avoid RegEx if you're like me and are clueless about it :)

Comment: @JimBobBennett The string has other spaces in it that need to stay.  :/

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc don't forget replace returns a copy, so you can use it for the IndexOf and it won't impact the original string

Comment: @JimBobBennett - That'd make a good answer.

Comment: @Bobson changed to answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I'd advise you against trying to parse HTML with regular expressions. There's libraries, such as HtmlAgilityPack for parsing HTML and all its weird rules.

That said, this is a simple enough case that a regular expression should be sufficient.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(scheduleString, @"<br\s*/>")) return scheduleString;
```

This will match `<br` followed by any number of whitespace (including 0), followed by `/>`.  Because we're not using anchors (`^` for start of string, `$` for end of string), this will match if that string is anywhere within `scheduleString`, regardless of what else is there.  If you wanted to match *just* the `<br/>` tag, you'd use `@"^<br\s*/>$"`.

Comment: The entire string isn't HTML.  It just contains one HTML tag.  Can you explain the regex part?  I'm not too familiar with regex.  Will this consider the fact there could be characters before and after the `<br/>` ?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc - I added an explanation line around when you made that comment.  Is that sufficient, or would you like more?

Comment: The `scheduleString` may or may not have characters before the `<` and after the `>`.  It doesn't seem this regex covers that condition

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc - How's that?

Comment: Never mind!  I did something wrong on my end to cause that.  This solution works!

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.replace()` to remove the spaces, then do the check.

```
if (scheduleString.Replace(" ", "").IndexOf("<br/>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1) return scheduleString;
```

The `string.Replace()` method returns a copy (strings being immutable and all that) so there's no worries about it affecting the original string.

This may not be the fastest if you are checking a lot of strings.  I've added `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to avoid any case issues - it is good practice for html to be in lower case but you never know.

Comment: This is much simpler than mine.  +1, but you might want to include your "this is a copy" comment too.

Comment: Excellent.  Given the scenario, and assuming that only spaces are at issue, I would recommend this method over my answer.  Sometimes, I go right for the complicated answer when a simple one would do.

Comment: This is not ideal. A string "<        b  r  />" will be recognized as valid. The question specifies that the space should be between "br" and "/>"